# Create thumb in Yii2

Tags: yii2, thumbnails, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

I have used this link to insatll yii2-imagine:
[ThumbCreate](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/757/how-to-use-imagine-crop-thumb-effects-for-images-on-yii2/)

When it successfully run, then in `/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Imagine/` folder there is one folder `vendor` and then in that folder there are 2 more folders with name `imagine` and `composer` . In `imagine` folder there is one more folder with same name and then in that folder there are so many folders and file. i am attaching image for that[image].
 **Now, how can i use thumbnail function to make thumbs of images.**

**composer.json file**

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-imagine",
    "description": "The Imagine integration for the Yii framework",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "imagine", "image", "helper"],
    "type": "yii2-extension",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-imagine/issues",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-imagine"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Antonio Ramirez",
            "email": "amigo.cobos@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-imagine": "*",
        "imagine/imagine": "0.5.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "yii\\imagine\\": ""
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.0.x-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

**controller file**

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Employee;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\UploadedFile; // upload the image in folder
use yii\Imagine\Image;
use vendor\ExportXLS; // for export data in excel file

class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Employee();
        $model->added_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'avatar');

            if(!empty($model->file)) {
                $imageName = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
                $model->file->saveAs('uploads/emp/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
                $model->avatar = $imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
                $originalFile = Yii::$app->basePath.'/uploads/emp/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
                $thumbFile = Yii::$app->basePath.'/uploads/emp/thumb/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;

                $saveThumb = Image::thumbnail($originalFile, 200, 200)->save($thumbFile, ['quality' => 80]);
            }
            if($model->save()){
                $this->redirect(\Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('employee'));
            }
        }
        else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' =>  $model
                ]);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

How can i make the thumb? after uploading the image. Tell if more info is needed.

Answer (score 2):

1.please download yii2-imagine from https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-imagine

2.extract file in advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2   and then rename "yii2-imagine-master" to the "imagine"

3.open the advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\classes.php   and insert these two line

```
 'yii\imagine\Image' => YII2_PATH . '/imagine/Image.php',
 'yii\imagine\Image' => YII2_PATH . '/imagine/BaseImage.php',
```

in the return[ ]  like other line.

4.now please go to frontend or backend and open one of your views or controllers and then add below code on top

```
 use yii\imagine\Image;
```

now your class is added and then you can use the Image::  as the below.

```
 Image::thumbnail($filename, $width, $height);
```

or other methods that's you want to use.

best regards.